# menu.add in java won't take NONE as valid integer

Tags: java, android

As the title says, I'm trying to add an item to a menu using the `menu.add()` method. The args for this are: `menu.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRES)`. The docs say that for `groupId` and `order` the value `NONE` can be attributed to them if they are not required. Eclipse won't accept NONE as a valid integer value however.

Can anyone help me with this?

There's not much point posting a code snippet!

Comment: uhm, if you refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html you probably just need to write Menu.NONE, and not NONE on its own, or you doing that?

Comment: if that doesnt work, you could just insert 0 (as NONE is declared as 0). even though its bad practice

Comment: @schippi thanks I'm new to Java/Android so still finding my way around. andrew_pako has given me the correct answer but thanks for pointing me to the right place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menu.add(groupId, itemId, android.view.Menu.NONE, titleResId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Integer instead of int?